# can not see the values in ajax toolkit combobox using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have created a sample application with Asp.net-Ajax. I have added AjaxControlToolkit.dll controls in my asp.net application toolbox and added a combobox with two items in it but when I run application the added items are not shown in the combobox. Why this is happening can anyone help me? See the code-

Tanks.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"                Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>

        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" 
            AutoPostBack="False" 
         DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
         AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" 
         CaseSensitive="False" 
         CssClass="" 
         ItemInsertLocation="Append">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Sumit Sharma</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Amit Sharma</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ComboBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat ="server" OnClick="Button5_Click" Text="Click To Select Item"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to replace the scriptmanager by toolscriptmanager

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```